# Defining property of type function/procedure pointer in Delphi 2010 RIDL editor

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2010, idl

I am wondering if it is possible to define property of type function/procedure pointer in Delphi 2010 RIDL editor, for an interface definition, such that when I create an instance of its implementor using its CoCreator, I may then assign a function/procedure in my source that uses that interface definition, to that property. Actually I want to know how to fill "**???**" on the following.

TLB file:

```
IComIntf = interface(IDispatch)
...
  function Get_OnDoSomething : ??? safecall;
  procedure Set_OnDoSomething(const New_Event : ???); safecall;
...
  property OnDoSomething : ???;
...
implementation

uses ComObj;

class function CoComIntf.Create: IComInt;
...
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_ComIntf) as IComIntf;
end;
```

implementation file, ComIntfUnit.pas:

```
type
  TOnDoSomething = function (Info: OleVariant): HResult of object;

TComIntf = class(TAutoObject, IComIntf)
private
  fOnDoSomething : TDoSomething;
...
public
  property OnDoSomething: TOnDoSomething read fOnDoSomething write fOnDoSomething;
...
```

Client form:

```
uses ComIntfUnit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  { Private declarations }
    fCom : IComIntf;
    function DoSomething(Info: OleVariant): HResult;
  public
  { Public declarations }
...
  end;
...

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fCom := CoComIntf.Create;
  fCom.OnDoSomething := DoSomething;
...
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw function pointers are not COM compatible types. You could certainly use a void pointer if you wished but that wouldn't really be in the spirit of COM.

What you are expected to do here is to pass another interface. Then the callee can call a function on that interface and have the caller's code be executed.

Comment: Hi David, and thank you for your prompt reply. So what about the assignment in the client program. Please elaborate this more. fCom.OnDoSomething := DoSomething;

Comment: It can't be done. Not for an interface that supports dispatch. You can't use function pointers. There's a reason why the ridl editor doesn't allow that. Use an interface instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way.  The correct way to implement this is to define a second interface that the client implements and passes to your COM object.  The COM object can then hold on to that interface and call methods on it when needed.  This is most commonly implemented using [Connection Points](http://www.techvanguards.com/com/concepts/connectionpoints.asp) for event interfaces.

An easy way to implement this, especially since you are using `IDispatch`, is to create a new **Automation Object** using the IDE wizard, and be sure to click on the "Generate Event support code" checkbox in the wizard dialog.  The wizard will then generate 2 interfaces, one for the object itself, and one for the object's events, and implement the connection point logic for you.  You can then add methods to the 2 interfaces as needed, where the object methods call the event methods when needed.

If you then compile, register, and import the final object into the IDE and generate a VCL wrapper for it, the resulting component will have VCL-style events on it that are internally hooked up to the object's connection point events.

Comment: Hi Remy, I am wondering if your method will let me to use IComIntf definition in asked way. As I understood from what David Heffernan said, it is not possible. Actually I have implemented this using the class that implemented the interface, and added the definition of the private members and their related public or published properties to let the client to define and assign the procedural pointer assignment, and also the VCL wrapper method. Internally in that class I have created IEvent and used InterfaceConnect/Disconnect. The way I was interested was to use the interface definition itself.